# ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor Views (cshtml Files) hosted on IIS 7.5 seem to be cached somehow (no client or outputcaching)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, razor, iis-7.5

we have a caching issue when editing cshtml files. Our ASP.net MVC 3 application is hosted with IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008. Now, when we edit a cshtml file the changes won't show until we reset iis - which is something we do not want to do too frequently on our production system.

According to fiddler, STRG-F5 and Firebug it's not a client-side caching issue (which would have been weird anyway). So no caching related HTTP headers are sent to the client. We do have staticContent configured in our web.config though.

There's no OutputCaching configured in anyway for the corresponding controller actions, either. Actually, we do not use OutputCaching at all in this project. We couldn't find much on the internet and are kinda puzzled at what is actually happening here.

Any idea why IIS, ASP.Net MVC or something in between the client and the web server is seemingly caching the content of cshtml files?

Related views are no child views.

Note: this is not an issue with cassini. Also, Partial Views with dyamic content within an updated View behaves correctly. Which also leads to the conclusion (for me) that it's not related to OutputCaching whatsoever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a proxy between server and client? If you press Ctrl+F5 in the browser, does it return cached content?

Comment: Did you disabled outputcaching in Controller? something like [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Comment: Of course we tried STRG-F5 and other things first. We sniffed network traffic and http headers and all that stuff. i mentioned this in the question. output caching is not explicitly disabled but it's not enabled, either.

Comment: i probabely would suggest the solution provided by @StefanP. Because i faced smae kind of issue a way back and its working for me from then, +1 for it. i think it might be a issue with application pool recycling check this [link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling).

Comment: thanks for the hints stefan and razor. i'll check this out

Comment: @360Airwalk, i have the same problem here, can i know what did you do to solve this? thanks

Comment: better late then never: i found no solution to it. the biggest problem is that i cannot safely reproduce the behaviour. i'm sorry to disappoint, still searching for the source of the problem myself.